# Which design pattern for an alerter

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm really struggling to come up with a design pattern for an Alerter I'm building.  Here's a contrived example of what I'm trying to do:

A person wants to get an alert by weather type (rain, snow, sun, etc.).  A person also has a choice of alert method (email, sms, slack channel, hipchat room, etc.)

I need to: have a class which takes in a weather type.  Then it retrieves all the people that care about that weather type.  Then it loops through all the people and sends them their alert (based on the person's alert type preference).

Here's my basic outline, but it seems like it should be done "better":

```
public class Alerter
{
    private readonly WeatherType _weatherType;

    public Alerter(WeatherType weatherType)
    {
        _weatherType = weatherType;
    }

    public void SendAlerts()
    {
        var people = PersonRepository.GetPeople(_weatherType);

        foreach (Person person in people)
        {
            switch (person.AlertType)
            {
                case Email:
                    var e = new EmailAlerter();
                    e.SendToPerson(person, _weatherType);
                    return;
                case SMS:
                    var s = new SmsAlerter();
                    s.SendToPerson(person, _weatherType);
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to discuss an algorithm or a design pattern probably you should post the question to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Steve when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat absolutely correct, my fault here, but I was so taken away from a meta post seen on programmers that I have completely forgotten

Comment: I've voted to close this and I've posted in programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/331915/which-design-pattern-for-an-alerter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx%22generics%22)

Like this:

```
public class Alerter<T>
{
    private readonly WeatherType _weatherType;

    public Alerter(WeatherType weatherType)
    {
        _weatherType = weatherType;
    }

    public void SendAlerts()
    {
        var people = PersonRepository.GetPeople(_weatherType);

        foreach (Person person in people)
        {
            var e = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            e.SendToPerson(person, _weatherType);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also replace the weather type with an other generic.

Comment: Don't you get stuck with doing a big switch statement, based on the type of alert (email, sms, etc.) that needs to be fired?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a publish & subscribe pattern. There are a number of ways to implement said pattern, here's a link to start you off (but certainly do take a look at others before you decide which will work best for you):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254(v=vs.110).aspx

You could potentially couple it with an Event aggregator - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx

Comment: You might be right, but I'm not sure how to adapt my code above into it - isn't it already kind of publishing to the subscribers?

Comment: Yes it does appear to be publishing to your list of subscribers. But to complete the pattern you may want to include event raising/listening separate to your current alerter. Here's an example I found with more detail: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866547/Publisher-Subscriber-pattern-with-Event-Delegate-a